# Why is the ls command with a wildcard only returning the first match when run within a script?

Tags: bash, ls

The directory contents:

```
newfile1 newfile2 oldfile1 oldfile2
```

my script

```
arg="${1}"
ls "${arg}"
```

Input is newfile*

The output

```
newfile1
```

Expected output

```
newfile1 newfile2
```

Why don't I get what's expected?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `ls *new` will undergo the same pathname expansion in a script as it does on the command line. What isn't shown is what you do after the `ls *new` in the script. Though something tells me [Bash Pitfalls **#1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) may be relevant -- there is a reason that's `#1`. Provide the details requested by Cyrus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't mean *Input is newfile**, but really mean *the program is called as `bash SCRIPTNAME newfile*`*.

You fetch only the first parameter inside the script. Since the wildcard `newfile*` expands the files in alphabetical order, the invocation is equivalent to

```
bash SCRIPTNAME newfile1 newfile2 oldfile1 oldfile2
```

Hence, `$1` is *newfile1* and you are doing just a `ls newfile1`.

To fetch all parameters passed to your script as a list, use `"$@"`. To fetch them as a single string, use `"$*"`.

Comment: Doh! My script is actually complex and the problem is internal. But your post made me realize this is the exact effect you're describing